# Jasmine/Protractor. it block loop requires BeforeAll to run. BeforeAll won't run without it block

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I am having a bit of a chicken or the egg scenario with a spec I'm working on.

I have a beforeAll function, which goes to my webpage and populates a list `componentList` based on elements from the page.

I then want to use those elements to execute some other tests. Which I have done like so:

```
componentList.map(componentName => {
    it('should use component to do some stuff...', () => {
        //execution in it block which requires component names
    });
};
```

My issue is that it can't actually access this it block, because the `componentList` is empty. The component list is empty, because the beforeAll will only be carried out once it sees an it block. But it can't see an it block because... etc.

Any ideas how I can get around this?
I can't put all the code in one it block because it would take too long to run.

Comment: Why did you even wrap your `it` inside `componentList`? Shouldn't you populate the list inside `beforeall` and then inside `it` use the list?

Comment: @FCin Using the list inside of a singe `it` will mean the `it` would be running for a very long time. Is this not bad practice? I would rather several `it` blocks than one that takes 30 minutes to run

Comment: I don't think you can create your own `it` blocks at run time, so your approach won't work. You need to define `it` blocks explicitly and then the only option is to use `componentList` inside `it` blocks.